# How can I unify this list instead of just adding more variables to it?

Tags: prolog

I'm doing a project in college and I'm trying to use Prolog, in this case I have to run trough the elements of the list three by three, but I've not been successful at unifying the list with the correct variables (X, Y, Z) and my program keeps adding more and more variables to the list.

```
aplica_R1_fila_aux(Fila, N_Fila) :-
   copia(Fila, N_Fila).
aplica_R1_fila_aux(Fila, [X,Y,Z|T]) :-
   aplica_R1_Triplo([X,Y,Z], F),
   aplica_R1_fila_aux(Fila, T).
```

This code it should copy the list Fila to N_Fila then unify [X,Y,Z|T] with N_Fila and change the list but instead it just keeps adding variables to N_Fila.

Comment: Please give a concrete query and its expected result.

Comment: *This code it should copy the list `Fila` to `N_Fila` then unify `[X,Y,Z|T]` with `N_Fila` and change the list*. That is a description of implementation detail. What is the program intended to accomplish?

Comment: The program is supposed to go through the list Fila in sub-lists of three elements(for example, Fila = [a,b,c,d,e,f], it should operate on [a,b,c] then [b,c,d], and so on till the last element), apply the conditions from aplica_R1_triplo and N_Fila should be the output which is the list Fila altered by the function. Could you understand or was it unclear ? Thank your for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The main trick you need to make this work is that you can use `call/N` with varying numbers of arguments. So once you have peeled off `X`, `Y` and `Z`, you can obtain the result of your `Goal` against them with `call(Goal, X, Y, Z, Result)`.

There are several ways to do this, but I would prefer to just make three sublists and recur on all three of them. When the rightmost one is exhausted, you are done recurring. This gives you fewer base cases to worry about (lists with no, one or two elements do not need to be handled separately) and there are no cuts so your code will wind up looking like this:

```
map3(Goal, [X,Y,Z|L], Solutions) :-
    map3(Goal, [X,Y,Z|L], [Y,Z|L], [Z|L], Solutions).

map3(_, _, _, [], []).
map3(Goal, [X|XR], [Y|YR], [Z|ZR], [R|Rest]) :-
    call(Goal, X, Y, Z, R),
    map3(Goal, XR, YR, ZR, Rest).
```

This could also be solved without the helper predicate, but there was something that offended me about it and this really shouldn't be much worse in terms of expense, so this is the way I went.

With a dummy goal of `foo(X,Y,Z, foo(X,Y,Z))`, I got this example query and result:

```
?- map3(foo, [a,b,c,d,e,f], Result).
Result = [foo(a, b, c), foo(b, c, d), foo(c, d, e), foo(d, e, f)] ;
false.
```

I think this is basically what you are trying to get, let me know if I can clarify anything.